# Compare image in picture-box to default image

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, default, picturebox

I assigned `Picturebox.Image` to Default image. But It still pass the If-statement and open new Diaglog. I don't know why? Please help me!

```
private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (imgBox.Image == Properties.Resources.DefaultImage || imgBox.Image == Properties.Resources.EmptyPhoto)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Warning! Cannot save this image!");
    }
    else
    {
        SaveNoti save = new SaveNoti();
        save.sender = new SaveNoti.SEND(Task_functions);
        save.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: The equals is comparing references. You need to implement the equals for images and then compare bytestreams. Still, if there's just a tiny change to the image the bytestreams will be different and the equals check will fail. You should probably find a different solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each time you read the image from resources you get a **new copy** and then `==` will return `false` (because it obviously compares by reference). If you will ever use bitmaps from resources in GDI+ graphics...you'd better remember this.

Save them somewhere:

```
static readonly Image DefaultImage = Properties.Resources.DefaultImage;
static readonly Image EmptyPhone = Property.Resources.EmptyPhoto;
```

Then be sure to **always use them** to assign `imgBox.Image` property (where you assign the default value):

```
imgBox.Image = DefaultImage; // Do not use Properties.Resources.DefaultImage
```

Now you can check for equality (inside the click handler):

```
if (imgBox.Image == DefaultImage || imgBox.Image == EmptyPhoto)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Warning! Cannot save this image!");
}
```

If you use it more than once just extract a method:

```
private bool IsDefaultImage
    => imgBox.Image == DefaultImage || imgBox.Image == EmptyPhoto;
```

Comment: It's not correct! And the warning at line `imgBox.Image = DefaultImage;` is "This parameter is not valid"

Comment: @HuuTin I'm assuming `Properties.Resources.DefaultImage` is `Image` or `Bitmap` (and few other things because I do not see your code), unless you post your whole project then you should adapt to your specific case, no??? BTW what's that _warning_?

Comment: But thank you a lot! I try to use a bool parameter (IsDefaultImage) like you to check If-statement,   and it is the easier way.

Comment: Boolean? Hmpf...I don't appreciate the way. You'd better abstract the whole thing away (introducing a separate class `DefaultImages` with all relevant logic but...anyway up to you

Comment: Comment about your code: **do not dispose the previous image**, you're not creating a new one each time then it will fail at run-time. BTW Assignment has not to be inside the click handler but when you assign the image... :O

Comment: If you want to check the error. My code is in  below answer. The warning is "DefaultImage is not valid"

Comment: Is it a compiler warning or a run-time error? In both cases please post full error message. Also: do not dispose the image (we're reusing it) and (equally important) do not assign the default image inside the click handler (where you should only perform comparison...)

Comment: At initially, I assigned `picturebox.Image` as default image in resources. So when I clicked `Save` button, I want to dispose it. And as you say, I try to assign another image to picturebox but it still work.

Comment: Since my target is determining whether I assign the default image to `picture-box`, if not the save button will work. I call Dispose() because I assign many images to `picture-box`. If I don't do that, sometimes It runs out of memory.

Comment: I understand but...you should dispose (that's right) before you assign new one (not before saving) and only if it's not default image (which can't be recreated each time exactly because of the problem you found). To assign in the click handler will ALWAYS exit without saving (if code is the one you posted)

Comment: It's not the whole project, just a small part. I save the image not in the button click. I just do that for example. Btw, thank you so much for helping a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct! This is my code:

```
static readonly Image DefaultImage = Properties.Resources.DefaultImage;
static readonly Image EmptyPhone = Property.Resources.EmptyPhoto;  
private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            imgBox.Image.Dispose();
            imgBox.Image = DefaultImage;
            if (imgBox.Image == DefaultImage)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Warning! Cannot save this image!");
            }
            else
            {
                SaveNoti save = new SaveNoti();
                save.sender = new SaveNoti.SEND(Task_functions);
                save.ShowDialog();
            }
```

The result at line `imgBox.Image = DefaultImage;` is Parameter is not valid